# Расшарить подключение к интернету на несколько сетевых соединений

Tags: windows, сеть

Имеется сервер с двумя сетевыми картами. Через первую сервер подключен к интернету. Это подключение расшарено на подключение к другому компьютеру (вторая сетевая карта), чтобы он тоже имел доступ к интерету (делается так: Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections -> соединение_с_провайдером -> Properties -> Sharing -> Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection)В соответствующем поле указывается имя сетевого соединения, которое получит доступ к интернету.Собственно, вопрос в заголовке.

P.S.: Возможно, вопрос выглядит запутанным, но я надеюсь, что меня поймут.

P.S.2: Да, я понимаю, что для таких задач существуют роутеры. Но интересует именно способ без роутеров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну я думаю что все соединения но которые требуется раздать интернет надо объединить в мост после чего в (Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections -> соединение_с_провайдером -> Properties -> Sharing -> Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection) выбрать тот самый сетевой мост

Объединяйте сетевухи в мост. Расшаривайте инет после объединения. У моста будет ай-пи 192.168.0.1. На подключаемых компах должны быть настройки TCP\IP: 192.168.0.2(3), 255.255.255.0, 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.1 (последний адрес DNS может быть отличный от этого если у прова настройки сервера не предоставляют его автоматически, поэтому нужно узнать альтернативные DNS в сети вашего провайдера(либо 8.8.8.8, думаю тоже будет работать) и прописать, но для начала попробуйте 0.1)

Answer (score 1):

А не рассматривается вариант с линуксом на сервере?

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADEiptables -P FORWARD ACCEPTecho 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: Нет, это не тот случай. Но за инфу спасибо :)